# Repair HDMI HPD and EDID failure

Tags: i2c, repair, debugging, eeprom, hdmi

[image: Video board]

This is a photo of an old video board from a Dell display showing "No Cable", and "No Signal" OSD messages but working correctly when video is force-enabled and EDID is supplied externally.

Inside those red selections are the EEPROMs that have stopped being detected as I2C devices (not found by `i2cdetect`, HDMI EDID negotiation and HPD failure).

I have also ensured that the HDMI cable and the source aren't at fault by hooking up the same to a known good sink, and the faulty monitor to another working cable and a Raspberry Pi source.

**Questions:**

If you look closely at the pins of these three ICs, they all look charred / badly oxidized.

Does this indicate that these chips might have got burnt or this is just oxidation (even though I haven't seen this level of oxidation anywhere else on the board; the main controller's pins are all shiny. The photo was taken after rubbing the pins with Q-tips and brushing with 99.9% marketed IPA)?

Meanwhile, I had ordered the closest replacement that I could source.

I have read datasheets of these EEPROMs; they are the SGS-Thompson [24C02-R](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15sO2ZQ2Rd0kbUxDGAcUtkbnyWDntBsPZ/view?usp=sharing) (maybe one is for the HDMI port, the other one for the VGA), and the [24C16-W](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rEwa_BgI8774HOaSW7EBh5_XxIXz1JTM/view?usp=sharing) (maybe it's for the monitor settings or DDC/CI).

The one I ordered is an [24C16-R](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ImaBPWZ1j_nY1EE_vCh3qiJkM8Ki6pCE/view?usp=sharing). It's up to specifications, but has a larger memory array as compared to the 24C02, but byte-addressable.

Would this work? Do micro-controllers / circuits generally accept larger EEPROMs or does it depend on the controller itself?

Next time I'll continuity check the SDA, SCL, DDC/CI and HPD pins of the HDMI port on the video board, by connecting a cable between another board with the HDMI port surface mount pins exposed.

Is it possible to test an EEPROM in-circuit that is not communicating with the I2C bus?

**Strange history:**

This monitor had worked well for a long time before it happened. Nothing out of the ordinary, just a screen timeout and it stopped working.

But I have seen 'Awakenings' though, after the HDMI handshake not working for a year or so, one day when rebooting the computer I saw the UEFI firmware screen and subsequently took a dump of the EEPROM using `edid-decode`; `i2cdetect` and `ddcutil` were working too then. The [dump](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RMWzV0_zwa62atVBaCHK61kbQQCl_qR2/view?usp=sharing) was csum accurate.

EDID negotiation worked for a week or so before it gave up again. It had been a year since then and I haven't seen it working again.

I have used it so far by utilizing the Linux kernel's DRM external EDID block facility.

Apart from the EDID negotiation, the display is completely usable. I would like to fix this fault to be able to access the UEFI environment since there is no mechanism for the external EDID.

**References:**

[A technical presentation (training material) on Troubleshooting HDMI systems by Neal Kendall, Quantum Data.](https://www.quantumdata.com/assets/780_psg.pdf)

Comment: How do you even know the chips are bad? All it takes is some other problem such as missing power supply and the chips won't communicate. Even if you replace the chips, you don't know the full contents. The larger chip might be for storing monitor settings.

Comment: When your new EEPROMs arrive, they'll presumably be blank. What data do you intend to load into them to make them useful?

Comment: Beg borrow or steal an oscilloscope and check those waveforms. The tarnish on the surface is interesting but not diagnostic.

Comment: As I wrote, I did had a chance to take a dump of 256 bytes EDID eeprom (one of the 24C02) when it worked. Also, there is a project named [linuxhw](https://github.com/linuxhw/EDID) where you can find most monitor's EDIDs.

Comment: I think the chips are bad because they look different than the rest of the board, presumably burnt and this is usually the problem with EDID issues. Though, I would have taken Vcc measurements the next time (My DMM's battery were down that time so I couldn't trust the measurements. But let just say the supply is present).

Comment: There use to be two eeproms present on i2c bus address 0x50 and 0x51 related to this monitor. Now there is non. I think the bigger chip might be DDC/CI data, as I read somewhere.

Comment: Thanks @Bryan, I would if I could. I appreciate that you found the tarnish interesting too.

Comment: Burned chips are not usual in EDID issues. Where do you got this info? Also, if you said already you have HPD issues, then that is the issue, because EDID is not read unless PC detects HPD correctly. Please, don't randomly change chips unless you know for sure they are broken.

Comment: Thanks @ocrdu for some serious proofreading. Next time, I'll pay more attention.

Comment: I meant to say that the failed EEPROMs are usually the cause of EDID related issues. I wouldn't swap the chips without being certain that is the cause of failure. Also, I'll look more closely into the HPD circuit. Maybe the pull-up resistor on the HPD line be the cause of failure here. I'll update my findings.

Comment: I haven't looked at the spec sheets. Larger arrays (with more pages) will fail if the addressing uses an extra word.

Comment: they look fine. Sounds more likely that there is a bus issue. A scope on the SDA/SCL lines would tell you a lot. Very unlikely that these 3 chips have somehow all failed when all else on the board is OK. Doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Agreeable. I am leaning toward diagnosing hotplug-detect issues. Only after then I'll try to read these chips using the RPi GPIO. I don't have a VGA cable laying around otherwise a quick connection to the VGA port can confirm if the second EDID eeprom is working there.

Comment: If monitor says "no cable" then it is not an DDC/EDID/Hotplug issue. Monitor just does not detect that cable is plugged into monitor, or it can't detect the other end is plugged into PC.